# How to convert a directory of jpg files to a pdf with filenames as bookmarks?

Tags: pdf, pdftk, bookmarks

I have a directory of jpg files that are scans of my handwritten notes. How do I convert them to a single pdf file that has the filenames as bookmarks?

(I eventually also want to add ocr. As mentioned online, we can convert the `.jpg` files to a `.pdf` using `img2pdf .jp --output combined.pdf`, and then we can add ocr using `ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf`. My question is mainly about how to also make sure the pdf file has bookmarks (created from filenames) so that the document is easy to navigate.)

Comment: Maybe check [@siddharth-pant 's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265208/123460) and preprocess your image files into the format it requires.

Comment: You mean some sort of table of contents on the first page that links to individual pages named after the jpg filenames?

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick convert can convert jpg images to a pdf file.

```
convert *.jpg document.pdf
```

It may happen that ImageMagick will refuse to do it with a message like this

```
convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
```

In that case, use advice from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

ImageMagick will make a pdf without bookmarks. You will have to add them with the help of this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304718/create-bookmarks-into-a-pdf-file-via-command-line.

If you make a script that will sort jpg files (one per page), you will know which jpg is on each page. First, you will have to specifiy each jpeg file

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg ... z.jpg output.pdf
```

Then you will set a bookmark a.jpg to the first page, b.jpg to the second, and so on. In that way, you should be able to add bookmarks, too.

I guess you have some scripting/programming to do, but I am positive that it can be done.